# woocommerce - primary category and multiple subcategories on one product

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce, categories

I'm building a webshop with Wordpress and Woocommerce. I'm wondering if there's any way to give one primary category and multiple subcategories to a product?

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple categories, just check them in the Product Categories box, the same as for a post. Or you could assign 1 category and then use Product Tags for multiple terms.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know I can do that, but I want to be able to assign a primary category(for menu purposes)

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but your question was kind of thin. Maybe if you edit to try to explain what "menu purpose" you are trying to achieve I could give a better answer.

Comment: I'm assuming this is to do with what is considered the "primary" category when multiple are used for a product. This is useful for example when a product page displays a breadcrumb and what is displayed as the category in the breadcrumb trail.